# Reading request: Books like Spivak's differential geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, book-recommendation

Are there any series in mathematics which take a simlar approach to Spivak's differential geometry in other fields?

I am currently coming towards the end of the second volume and have greatly enjoyed being able to get a sense for the ideas and how he continually builds up on simple ideas such as the oscullating circle up to the modern definitions of curvature.

I would be particularly intested in seeing this approach applied to algebraic geometry, as it seems as though its history could shed much light on the development of modern algebra and to algebraic topology, whose very abstract definitions leave me wondering where they came from.

Comment: Hatcher's Algebraic Toplogy is free and very good.

Comment: By and large no; Spivak is a fairly unique individual who has done a massive service to differential geometry by writing that book. The student of algebraic geometry is largely on their own in working out the historical context. In that regard, there is a report by Zariski called *Algebraic Sheaf Theory* that you might want to seek out. It was written in the late 50s, so Zariski was at that point an elder statesman of the field describing how the new techniques were applicable to old problems.